# Creating and passing array from a form to controller using jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, form-for

I have a form (form_for) and I want the user to be able to select multiple "categories" using the select method.

```
= form_for @place, :url=>{:action=>"#"} do |f|
  #appended_wrapper
  .categories
    = f.label :categories, "Categories: "
    = f.select :categories, %w(Active Art Auto Food), {:include_blank => true}
  = f.submit "Submit"
```

Everytime the user selects a category, I have jQuery append a div with the value of the category so that users can see and remove the categories they've added.

```
$('#hotel_categories').change(function(){
  value = $(this).val();
  $('#appended_wrapper').append( '<div class="appended"> '+value+' <a class="remove" href="#">Remove</a></div>' );

  $('.remove').click(function(){
    $(this).parent(".appended").remove();
  });

});
```

When I press the submit button, I want all the selected categories to be passed to my controller in an array.

How do I achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside your div, add a hidden input field like this one:

```
<input name="category_ids[]" type="hidden" value="1">
```

The value represents the id of the category. Notice the square brackets next to category_ids. **All the hidden inputs have to have exactly the same name.**

The values will come through as an array in the params hash in your controller.

Comment: I am going to try this. Will get back to you guys.

Comment: Can the value simply be the actual string (i.e. "Active" or "Food") instead of the id of the category?

Comment: Thanks - this worked and rails recognizes the multiple selection as an array in the params hash!

Comment: @hyngyn yes, the value can be whatever you want it to be. It will all come through as strings anyway.